# HTML5 form required attribute. How to check required message has been shown?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a multi-page form with some input with required attribute. I want to hide or show buttons if input with required attribute are empty or not.
How can I do this with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements that fail validation will match the `:invalid` pseudoselector. You can match on that to hide the next element:

```css
input:invalid {
  border-color: red;
}

input:invalid + span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input required>
<span>
  <button>Submit</button>
</span>
```

If you have multiple elements and you want to show or hide something based on whether anything is bad, you should know that the `<form>` containing `:invalid` elements is also `:invalid`:

```css
input:invalid {
  border-color: red;
}

input:valid + span {
  display: none;
}

form:invalid + div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input required>
  <span>First name required!</span>
  <br>

  <input required>
  <span>Last name required!</span>
  <br>
</form>
<div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably rename your question as it has nothing to do with "required message showing". In your case, you can try something like this:

```
var handlerFunction = function () {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#myForm input");
    var isEmpty = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].value === '') {
            hideButtons();
            isEmpty = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!isEmpty) {
        showButtons();
    }
};

var hideButtons = function () {
    // hide buttons
};

var showButtons = function () {
    // show buttons
};

var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#myForm input");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener("keydown", handlerFunction);
}
```

To use it you have to change `#myForm` to your form's id or class.
Here's the javascript solution that you wanted, but the solution above that uses css is a lot better (in case you don't need to use javascript).

Answer (score 0):

I would get the input and see if the content is equal to empty:

```
document.getElementById('inputRequire').innerText == '';
document.getElementById('inputRequire').value == '';
```

and then i show the other:

```
   var hiddenElements = document.getElementsByTagName('hiddenOnes');
foreach(...){
 element.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Something like that, i don't test the code but i think it can help you